# Is is bad practice to put a JSON request within a Dispatch_Async?

Tags: swift

Here is a Json request that I have for when the user logs in. In order to set up the profileView, I need to update the UI, which I do where I instantiate the next view controller. However, I need to make a second JSON request to get an image before I can fully update the profile. I can only make this second JSON request if the first JSON request is successful. Is it bad practice to create another JSON Request within the dispatch_async?

```
jsonRequest.get(userCookie, url: userURL) { (succeedCookie: Bool, msg: String, results: Dictionary<String, Any>) -> () in

    var gotUserInfo = false
    if(succeedCookie) {
        println("It twerked! - you got the cookie", error: msg)
    }
    else {
        println(("It didn't twerk .. :( you no get cookie", error: msg))
    }
    // Move to the UI thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        if gotUserInfo {
            //
            // Second JSON request goes here
            //
            let vcTwo = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("userProfile") as ProfileViewController
            //set future View variables here
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcTwo, animated: true)
        }  
    })
}
```

Comment: It seems unnecessary to call it from the main queue (that should probably be reserved solely for updating the UI), but it won't hurt anything since it will run in its own queue anyway. Why not call it just before you move to the main thread?

Comment: would that be before the closing bracket of the GET but outside the dispatch_async? I'm not familiar with what is within the boundaries of each thread